# How can I extract sub-strings using windows command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, string

For example say I have a file called testfile.txt that contains a list of file names of the following format:

```
A       svn\New Text Document.txt
M       svn\Table_tblVersion.xml
```

Is there a command that I can pipe testfile.txt into such that the first 8 characters of each line is removed. The output I want is simply:

```
svn\New Text Document.txt
svn\Table_tblVersion.txt
```

Comment: I think that you may find the answer in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-enviro).

Comment: It looks like windows command-line is not well suited for this task. Luckily I have the option of doing what I want in vb, so I'll be doing that instead I think!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `for` command against the file contents:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (testfile.txt) do echo %b
```

It's nowhere near as versatile as `cut` in [GnuWin coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), but it works.

Comment: variable names don't match, otherwise works good

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/et-ee/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) for such tasks. It's integrated with Windows 7 and you can download it for older versions of Windows.

The command is:

```
get-content testfile.txt | ForEach-Object {$_.Substring(8)} | write-host
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Step 2. `cut -c9-99 testfile.txt`

If you **must** use a pipe: `cat testfile.txt | cut -c9-99`